# mysql join three tables, replace id with its value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have three tables to use:

```
event Table

id | round | nameA | nameB | place
-- | ----- | ----- | ----- | -----
1  | 1     | 1     | 3     | 1
2  | 1     | 2     | 4     | 2

name Table

id | name | shortName | place
-- | ---- | --------- | -----
1  | A    | a         | 1
2  | B    | b         | 2
3  | C    | c         | 3
4  | D    | d         | 4

place Table

id | name
-- | ---
1  | p1
2  | p2
3  | p3
4  | p4
```

The event table is close to what I want but they are filled with ids instead. I want to replace ids with shortnames for both nameA, nameB as well as full place name like this:

```
nameA.shortName | nameB.shortName | place.name
--------------- | --------------- | ----------
 a              | c               | p1
 b              | d               | p2
```

So far I managed to do replace place id with its name and shortname for nameA

```
SELECT n.shortName, e.nameB,  p.name
FROM event e
  INNER JOIN name n
    ON  n.id = e.nameA
  INNER JOIN place p
    ON e.place = g.id
```

However nameB is still in its id

```
nameA.shortName | nameB.id        | place.id
--------------- | --------------- | ----------
 a              | 3               | p1
 c              | 4               | p2
```

I guess join and subquery. I know how to get the shortname and place name but how do you integrate them to the main query?

```
SELECT n.shortName
  FROM name n
    JOIN  event e
    ON n.id = e.nameB
```

Comment: Join name table twice. (Have table aliases, e.g. n1 and n2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table against the name table once for each field you want to value of:-

```
SELECT n1.shortName, 
        n2.shortName, 
        p.name
FROM event e
INNER JOIN name n1 ON  n1.id = e.nameA
INNER JOIN name n2 ON  n2.id = e.nameB
INNER JOIN place p ON e.place = g.id
```